# Better markdown syntax highlighting in sublime 2

Tags: sublime-text-2, syntax-highlighting, markdown

The markdown syntax highlighting in sublime text is fairly mediocre. Even when I install the markdown extended package it's still mostly displayed as plain white text. When I search `Markdown.tmLanguage` I can't find a single instance of `^#` in its matching patterns, suggesting it might not even have a mechanism for recognising headings.

Does anyone have either

- a better `Markdown.tmLanguage` file they can share
- advice on how I'd go about editing it to improve its interaction with my theme?

Answer (score 0):

It may be an issue with how your theme is handling the available Markdown scopes. If you're interested, check out the [`Neon Color Scheme`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme) on Package Control - I wrote it to take advantage of as many scopes as possible, in as many languages as possible, and the default `Markdown.tmLanguage` doesn't look too bad with it. Even if you don't like the colors I've chosen it might help you tweak your own theme more. If you have any suggestions on how I can make it better, or just have questions on theming in general, please [open an issue](https://github.com/MattDMo/Neon-color-scheme/issues/new) or submit a pull request and I'll do what I can to help out.

Searching through the `.tmLanguage` file has its uses, especially if you're looking for that one scope you can't seem to find but know should be there, but a much better way to go about improving your syntax highlighting theme is to use @facelessuser's [`ScopeHunter`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/ScopeHunter) plugin. I have it bound to a custom keybinding, and set up to display in a small panel at the bottom of the screen, and can find out what scopes are in effect under the cursor just by hitting a quick key sequence. Having the panel option set makes things a lot easier than using Sublime's built-in scope finder, as that only displays in the bottom bar, disappears fairly quickly, and can't be copied.